# Error in match(el, set, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments?

Tags: r, shiny

In running the following code in Shiny in R :

```
client_report_type = reactive({ input$report_type })
  if ( is.element(client_report_type,"Enterprise_user")) 

...
```

I encountered the following error message:

```
Error in match(el, set, 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Does anyone know what does it mean, and how to resolve the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: `client_report_type` is not a vector, as it states - it is probably a function or some other class of object that `match()` (which is called by `is.element`) can't make sense of. For instance, I can replicate the error by doing `is.element(mean, 1:5)`

Comment: Thanks. It seems that client_report_type is a "closure." How can I get the string or number out of a closure? Shouldn't reactive function return a string or a integer if the actual input is a string or an integer?

Comment: I have no idea - I've never used shiny but I guess you need to look at what `reactive` returns - see the "Value" section of `?reactive` I'm guessing to get a grasp on it.

Comment: Have you tried `client_report_type()` to return the value?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put an input inside a reactive to get the value, but the input should be inside of a reactive expression. Anything outside a reactive expression will be execute only once when the shiny app starts. And if you try to use an `input` value outside a reactive expression there will be an error. Depending of what you are going to do with `input$report_type` you can put it in a `reactive` (of course), `observe`, or `observeEvent`.

Here are some basic examples:

**reactive:**

```
dat <- reactive({ 
  if ( is.element(input$report_type,"Enterprise_user")) {
    ...
    myData
  } else {
    NULL
  }  
})
```

**observe:**

```
observe({
  if (is.null(input$report_type))
    return()

  if ( is.element(input$report_type,"Enterprise_user"))
   ...
})
```

**observeEvent:**

```
observeEvent(input$report_type, {
  if ( is.element(input$report_type,"Enterprise_user"))
   ...
})
```

Here is great tutorial about shiny and reactivity: http://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/#reactivity-101